# Android: Getting same notification again and again from GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I had implemented GCM in my app. From application server, I was supposed to get three different notifications. But, I am getting same notification again and again. While, from server side three different url's have been called. I am not getting, what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your server is not sending the notification over and over?

Comment: My server was sending different notifications every time. But, problem was there in my code. The varible that was holding messges received from server was not being passed to the notification manager. Instead, a hardcoded messgae was there.